# Is there a way to insert and centered in the header an image + a text, using react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to insert in my header a photo and a text using react navigation for a react native app.

To do so, I've try couple of things. All failed. For my previous shot, I've try to create a React component containing my image and my text and then used it as 'title' in the navigationOptions (code below).

```
// this is my component page
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class ImageHeader extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../../assets/pic.png')}
                    resizeMode='contain'
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Title_Page1
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    image: {
        width: 25,
        height: 25,
        zIndex: 999
    },

    text: {
        fontSize: 12
    }

})

// and then, in my navigation page:

        Page1: {
            screen: Page1,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: <ImageHeader/>
            }
        },
```

But unfortunately, I got this error: "Error: Invalid title for route "Page1" - title must be string or null, instead it was of type object".

I understand the error message, this way of doing is probably not possible. Would you guys have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `headerTitle` instead of title

```
navigationOptions: {
  headerTitle: <ImageHeader/>,
}
```

[image: header]